# IOS Crash Report - failed to exit in time

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports

I think the app is crashing when its minimized or closed.

Can someone help shed some light on the logs.
Is it possible to find out from the crash log if this is the case?
and what is causing the crash?

The app is called Flow, and here is the crash log:

```
Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
flow failed to exit in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 6.990 (user 6.990, system 0.000), 50% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.000, 0% CPU

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3aeb7fa8 __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3af1ef0a _pthread_mutex_lock + 302
2   CoreData                        0x301fdacc -[_PFLock lock] + 20
3   CoreData                        0x3020eba0 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator    executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 776
4   CoreData                        0x3020d7e2 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 610
5   Flow                            0x000bebe8 +[CDTSetAchievement SetAchievementWithAchievementObj:] (CDTSetAchievement.m:27)
6   Flow                            0x00182f88 -[HomeVC saveAchievementToCoreData:] (HomeVC.m:2290)
7   Foundation                      0x30decd68 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 740
8   Foundation                      0x30df0738 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 132
9   Flow                            0x0018277c -[HomeVC stepEditDone:withAchievementObj:withIsNew:] (HomeVC.m:2253)
10  Flow                            0x00104f0a __21-[StepEditVC goDone:]_block_invoke (StepEditVC.m:178)
11  Flow                            0x00228fec __53-[PFTask thenCallBackOnMainThreadWithBoolValueAsync:]_block_invoke (PFTask.m:341)
12  Flow                            0x00228dd6 __40-[PFTask thenCallBackOnMainThreadAsync:]_block_invoke_2 (PFTask.m:325)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x3addcd18 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x3addcd04 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x3ade3788 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 264
16  CoreFoundation                  0x30483814 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 4
17  CoreFoundation                  0x304820e8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1296
18  CoreFoundation                  0x303ecc22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
19  CoreFoundation                  0x303eca06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
20  GraphicsServices                0x3511327e GSEventRunModal + 134
21  UIKit                           0x32c90044 UIApplicationMain + 1132
22  Flow                            0x00148e4a main (main.m:23)
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x3ae01ab4 start + 0
```

This is the ApplicationDidFinishLaunching

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
#if !(APP_STORE_RELEASE)
    QTouchposeApplication *touchposeApplication = (QTouchposeApplication *)application;
    touchposeApplication.alwaysShowTouches = YES; 
#endif


[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:10.0];

self.arrayProgressIDs =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// First, register a handler for the product
[PFPurchase addObserverForProduct:IAP_UPGRADE block:^(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction) {
// NSLog(@"Description: %@",transaction);
}];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productPurchased:) name:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];


[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;

// Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;

// Optional: set Logger to VERBOSE for debug information.
[[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
// Initialize tracker. Replace with your tracking ID.
[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:GOOGLE_ANALYTICS];

id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
//    [tracker set:@"" value:@""];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];

[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"App Launching"];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];


[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];


self.arrayImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[Parse setApplicationId:APPLICATION_ID clientKey:CLIENT_KEY];
[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];
[PFTwitterUtils initializeWithConsumerKey:@"XXXXXX" consumerSecret:@"XXXXXXXXXXXX"];
// Set default ACLs
PFACL *defaultACL = [PFACL ACL];
[defaultACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
[PFACL setDefaultACL:defaultACL withAccessForCurrentUser:YES];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.homeVC= [[HomeVC alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav= [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.homeVC];
   nav.navigationBarHidden= YES;
self.leftVC= [[LeftVC alloc] init];
self.swipeVC= [[ECSlidingViewController alloc] init];
[self.swipeVC setUnderLeftViewController:self.leftVC];
[self.swipeVC setUnderLeftWidthLayout:ECFullWidth];
[self.swipeVC setTopViewController:nav];

if ([USER_DEFAULT boolForKey:IS_LOGIN])
{
    [self checkingFlowfromParse];
}

else
{
    FlashVC *introVC=[[FlashVC alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav= [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:introVC];
    nav.navigationBarHidden=YES;
    [self.window setRootViewController:nav];
}

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: show your applicationDidLaunch method. The problem must be there. You're performing something heavy on start, i think

Comment: @HutinPuylo I have added to the question.

Comment: i can't find something particular but i advise you to try to put in background thread everything that can be put in background (has no relation to UI) and see what happen

Comment: [HomeVC saveAchievementToCoreData:] and [CDTSetAchievement SetAchievementWithAchievementObj:] are likely where the problem lies. 

It looks as though you're doing something with CoreData that is causing a deadlock. If your application is unresponsive for 10+ seconds, it is killed by the OS.